# I'm unable to calculate the entropy of a .exe file

Tags: c, entropy

I'm trying to calculate the entropy of a .exe file by giving it as an input. However, I'm getting a zero value instead of an answer.

Entropy of a file can be understood as the the summation of (pi*log(pi)) every character in the file. I'm trying to calculate the entropy of a .exe file. However, I'm ending up getting a '0'. The '.exe' file for sure has an output.

Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdbool.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXLEN 100 

int makehist( char *S, int *hist, int len) {
   int wherechar[256];
   int i,histlen;
   histlen=0;
   for (i=0;i<256;i++)
       wherechar[i]=-1;
   for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
       if (wherechar[(int)S[i]]==-1) {
           wherechar[(int)S[i]]=histlen;
           histlen++;
       }
       hist[wherechar[(int)S[i]]]++;
   }
   return histlen;
}

double entropy(int *hist, int histlen, int len) {
    int i;
    double H;
    H=0;
    for (i=0;i<histlen;i++) {
        H-=(double)hist[i]/len*log((double)hist[i]/len);
    }
    return H;
}

void main() {
    char S[100];
    int len,*hist,histlen;
    int num;
    double H;
    int i=0;
    int count =0;
    FILE*file = fopen("freq.exe","r");
    while (fscanf(file,"%d",&num)>0)
    {
        S[i]=num;
        printf("%d",S[i]);

        i++;
    }

    hist=(int*)calloc(i,sizeof(int));

    histlen=makehist(S,hist,i);

    H=entropy(hist,histlen,i);
    printf("%lf\n",H);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Oh dear. what happened to your indentation? That's impossible to read.

Comment: When asking people to read your code, please format better. Indentation, spaces around operators (e.g. `for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)`), etc.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen ,@Almo thanks guys for suggesting

Comment: Novel idea - print out some intermediate results, eg. 'i' and 'histlen', or use an actual debugger to inspect their values.

Comment: i've done that..but it only shows me zero's nothing more than that!

Comment: From a glance, the most probable suspect is integer division...

Comment: You're trying to parse the exe file as a text file of numbers. Don't use fscanf. Use fgetc or fread to read the bytes.

Comment: @SJuan76 - that's what I thought at first:)

Comment: @Boann - OOPS..  didn't even look at the file read loop:)

Comment: Should open the file in binary mode. `fopen("freq.exe","rb");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be reading numbers:

```
fscanf(file,"%d",&num)
```

But I don't really expect to find many numbers in an EXE file.
They'd be random byte-values of all different types.

Numbers are only the digits `0-9` (and `-` & `+` signs as well).

Answer (score 2):

```
while (fscanf(file,"%d",&num)>0)
```

This reads numbers encoded as leading white space, optional sign, and a sequence of digits. As soon as some other character is encountered in your file (probably the first byte), your loop will stop. You need to read raw bytes, with `getc` or `fread`.

Also, please consider doing the most basic debugging before submitting a question to StackOverflow. Surely your printf in that loop never printed anything, yet you don't mention this in your question and apparently didn't investigate why.

Some other issues:

```
#define MAXLEN 100
```

This is never used.

---

```
void main()
```

This is not a valid definition of `main`. Use

```
int main(void)
```

---

```
char S[100];
```

You have undefined behavior if the input contains more than 100 chars, and a .exe file surely will. You really should be feeding the bytes into your histogram calculation as you read them, rather than storing them in a buffer. Easiest is to make `wherechar` and `histlen` globals, but you could also put everything you need into a struct and pass a pointer to the struct, together with each byte, to `makehist`, and again pass a pointer to the struct to `entropy`.

---

```
FILE*file = fopen("freq.exe","r");
```

Binary files must be opened with "rb" (doesn't matter on linux but does on Windows).
Also, you should check whether `fopen` succeeds.

---

```
hist=(int*)calloc(i,sizeof(int));
```

`hist` should have 256 elements. If you allocate this first, then you can process each byte as it is read per above.

---

You do a divide by zero in `entropy` if the file is empty ... you should check for `len` == 0.

---

`wherechar[(int)S[i]]` is undefined behavior if the file has chars with negative values, as it surely will. You should use `unsigned char` instead of `char`, and then the casts aren't necessary.